# Is there a way to merge two cells in column using google appscript in Google Docs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I was searching for a way to provide merge of two cells in a column. There is a way to merge it in a row with cell object and merge method, something like this:

```
var cells = [
   [
      'Row 1, Cell 1',
      'Row 1, Cell 2',
   ],
   [
      'Row 2, Cell 1',
      'Row 2, Cell 2'
   ]
];

// Build a table from the array.
var table = body.appendTable(cells);
var row = table.getRow(0);
var cell = row.getCell(1);
cell.merge();
```

So this is the result of the code above:
[image]

However what I want to achieve is this kind of merge:

[image]

Is it possible? There is such in functionality in UI, but can't find it in API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your question, I remember [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74635411). In the current stage, it seems that `merge()` has still not been able to be worked correctly, when I tested `merge()` again. So, in this case, I would like to propose using Google Docs API like that thread. But, in your expected result, my answer in that thread cannot be directly used. So, in this answer, I would like to propose a modified script for achieving your goal using Google Docs API.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var cells = [
    [
      'Row 1, Cell 1',
      'Row 1, Cell 2',
    ],
    [
      'Row 2, Cell 1',
      'Row 2, Cell 2'
    ]
  ];

  // Create a table.
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var id = doc.getId();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendTable(cells);
  doc.saveAndClose();

  // Use Google Docs API.
  var obj = Docs.Documents.get(id).body.content;
  var table = obj.reverse().find(({ table }) => table);
  var requests = [{ mergeTableCells: { tableRange: { columnSpan: 1, rowSpan: cells.length, tableCellLocation: { tableStartLocation: { index: table.startIndex }, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: cells[0].length - 1 } } } }];
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, id);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [MergeTableCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#mergetablecellsrequest)

Comment: Awesome mate, it does work flawlessly. I'm surprised there is a way to do that as I was going through most of the links in google and the API and couldn't find it. So it looks like you've used Docs.Documents API to achieve it. Is that mean the merge() method I tried to use in the first place is not part of Docs API and if so then does this mean it's more general function and can be also used more widely outside of Docs (in different google apps)?

Comment: @David Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `merge()` of the Document service (DocumentApp) and Docs API, the Document service has been released much before Docs API. I think that on the internal server side, the base program might be the same. But, I guessed that the process for using it might be different between the Document service and Docs API. I guess that this difference might be related to the reason for this issue. But, I'm not sure about the internal server side. So, this is just my guess. I apologize for this.

Comment: thanks for the input mate, I really appreaciate it